# Can I store the captured groupe strings/digits on a regex search?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to store the captured group contents in a regex search to variables

```
Dim input As String ="asdfd sdf dsf fdsf <disp-formula id=""deqn1-3""> fdsf fds df"
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("<disp-formula id=""deqn(\d+)-(\d+)"">")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(input)
    If match.Success Then
        \\ put the values represented by (\d+) and (\d+) in two variables and then use them in a loop
```

Can that be done in vb.net? If so how?

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `match`

```
Dim g1 = match.Groups(1).Value ' 1 in your sample
Dim g2 = match.Groups(2).Value ' 3 in your sample
```

Comment: How can I use all the integer values in the range from "g1" to "g2" and add it to different varibles i.e. I want to add a string ( id="deqn") to g1(which in the sample=1) and then to g1+1=2 until g1+2 which is in this case g2 = 3, basically I want to create strings
`Dim xyz1 As String =" id=""deqn1"""`, `Dim xyz2 As String =" id=""deqn2"""` and `Dim xyz3 As String =" id=""deqn3"""`

Comment: @TamalBanerjee You can't really create variable "on the fly" from some criteria. Meaning you can have `xyz1`, `xyz2`, `xyz3` depending on some calculated value. What you can do is have an array (or list or other data structure) with as many items as you need and init their values according to some calculated criteria. Hint : you probably need a loop for that. I let you try to do it by yourself

Comment: @TamalBanerjee If you do not succeed in achieving this I advise you to write another question explaining your problem (maybe linking to that answer for allowing people to have access to those comment) what you've tried (code, error message etc.), and how are you stuck, or any information which could be of help for other to help you